# Exception in thread "delete Spark local dirs" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-spark, sparkr

Hi i am running sparkr progrm through shell script. I pointed the input file to local means it is working fine,but when i point to hdfs means it throws error.

```
Exception in thread "delete Spark local dirs" java.lang.NullPointerException

Exception in thread "delete Spark local dirs" java.lang.NullPointerException
at  org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$DiskBlockManager$$doStop(DiskBlockManager.scala:161)
at  org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(DiskBlockManager.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(DiskBlockManager.scala:139)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(DiskBlockManager.scala:139)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1617)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager$$anon$1.run(DiskBlockManager.scala:139)
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Scala script. The problem was with the master URL, so I removed setting the master URL.

Previously:

```
val conf = new org.apache.spark.SparkConf().setMaster(masterURL).set("spark.ui.port",port).setAppName("TestScalaApp")
```

Fixed code:

```
val conf = new org.apache.spark.SparkConf().setAppName("TestScalaApp")
```